# How to serve cloudstorage files using app engine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk, google-cloud-storage, serving

In app engine I can serve cloudstorage files like a pdf using the default bucket of my application:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/<appid>.appspot.com/<file_name>
```

But how can I serve local cloudstorage files in the SDK, without making use of a blob_key?

I write to the default bucket like this:

```
gcs_file_name = '/%s/%s' % (app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(), file_name)
with gcs.open(gcs_file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

The name of the default bucket in the SDK = 'app_default_bucket'

In the SDK datastore I have a Kind: **GsFileInfo** showing: filename: /app_default_bucket/example.pdf

**Update and workaround: You can get a serving url for NON image files like css, js and pdf.**

```
gs_file = '/gs/%s/%s/%s' % (app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(), folder, filename)
serving_url = images.get_serving_url(blobstore.create_gs_key(gs_file))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local cloud storage files in the SDK"?

Comment: Files which were saved in my SDK default bucket.

Comment: There is no SDK default bucket. Only your application has a default bucket.

Comment: app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name() returns  'app_default_bucket'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE I found this feature to serve cloudstorage files using the SDK:**

[This feature has not been documented yet.](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133)

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/filename
```

This meands we do not need the img serving url to serve NON images as shown below !!!

To create e serving url for cloudstorage files like images, css, js and pdf's in the default_bucket, I use this code for testing(SDK) and GAE production:

**IMPORTANT: the images.get_serving_url() works also for NON images in the SDK!!**

In the SDK you stll need the blobstore to read a blob and create a serving url for a cloudstorage object.

I also added the code to read, write and upload cloudstorage blobs in the SDK and GAE production.

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133).

Answer (score 4):

This is the value that you see in the Development mode from app_identity_stub.py:

```
APP_DEFAULT_GCS_BUCKET_NAME = 'app_default_bucket'
```

The comments in this file explain it:

> This service behaves the same as the production service, except using
>   constant values instead of app-specific values

You should get the correct URL in your production code.

EDIT:

This is from the support forum:

> In development mode, the app engine tools simulate Google Cloud
>   Storage services locally. Objects in that simulated environment are
>   non-persistent so your app is failing because the desired object
>   doesn't exist in the local store. If you first create (and optionally
>   write to) the object you're trying to read, it should work fine in dev
>   mode (it did for me). Of course, objects in the production service are
>   persistent so there's no need for that extra step when running your
>   app in production mode (assuming the object already exists).
>
> Hope that helps,
>
> Marc Google Cloud Storage Team

This means you have to write a file first, then you can use it. If I understand correctly, you can use any bucket name for this purpose, including 'app_default_bucket'.

Comment: Yes, it works fine in production. But which SDK link to use to serve a file like example.pdf in the 'app_default_bucket'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still do not understand how to use it. How to serve the file in development mode?

Comment: Try replacing <appid>.appspot.com with app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(), and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried: http://localhost:8080/app_default_bucket/example.pdf but it returns a 404.

Comment: So it writes to this file name, but it does not read from it?

Comment: Yes. I hope Google will provide an answer or solution.

Comment: Update: Using get_serving_url you can read NON image files like pdf, css en js!!!

Comment: what is the equivalent `app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name` for go ? @AndreiVolgin

Answer (score 0):

I was here earlier looking for answers and just wanted to share what I found, now that I have it working.

You *can* do this now, and it's only a little painful. Tricking the image or blobstore API isn't supported and doesn't seem to work any longer.

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-gsutil

If you sign your URLs, you can give auto-expiring links to your content, for anonymous or paywalled consumption. You wouldn't want to serve your whole site this way, but for a PDF or whatnot, this is a valid and semi-secure option.

Missing from the documentation, you might need to drop the newline for the canonical extended headers. The storage endpoint will tell you what it expects when the signature is bad.

Also, your host should be: https://storage-download.googleapis.com/

If you're using App Engine, then the `GoogleAccessId` is: **<projectname>**@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

See: `app_identity.get_service_account_name()`

**Example of how to generate the signature:**

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity


def signFile(path, verb='GET', md5='', contentType='',
             expiration=''):
    signatureRequest = '{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(
        verb, md5, contentType, expiration, path)

    return app_identity.sign_blob(signatureRequest)
```

That returns a tuple of `(privateKey, binarySignature)`.

Now you need to construct the URL. The signature should be base64 encoded, then urlencoded. See the following for how to finish constructing the URL. You should probable use the download host mentioned above.

**Example URL from the docs:**

```
https://storage.googleapis.
com/example-bucket/cat.jpeg?GoogleAccessId=example@example-project.iam.gservicea
ccount.com&Expires=1458238630&Signature=VVUgfqviDCov%2B%2BKnmVOkwBR2olSbId51kSib
uQeiH8ucGFyOfAVbH5J%2B5V0gDYIioO2dDGH9Fsj6YdwxWv65HE71VEOEsVPuS8CVb%2BVeeIzmEe8z
7X7o1d%2BcWbPEo4exILQbj3ROM3T2OrkNBU9sbHq0mLbDMhiiQZ3xCaiCQdsrMEdYVvAFggPuPq%2FE
QyQZmyJK3ty%2Bmr7kAFW16I9pD11jfBSD1XXjKTJzgd%2FMGSde4Va4J1RtHoX7r5i7YR7Mvf%2Fb17
zlAuGlzVUf%2FzmhLPqtfKinVrcqdlmamMcmLoW8eLG%2B1yYW%2F7tlS2hvqSfCW8eMUUjiHiSWgZLE
VIG4Lw%3D%3D
```

I hope this helps someone!

Oh yeah, you only need to do all the signature stuff if your bucket isn't publicly accessible (read-all).