# image.ServingURL and Google Storage BlobKey not working on Development Server

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

Im running a local dev server and using image.ServingURL to create a url from a BlobKey that is stored in Google Storage.  Should this url return the image on a dev server?

I'm getting an error like such: `Could not find blob with key encoded_gs_file:<long_blob_key>`

Im using `blobstore.BlobKeyForFile(c, storageKey)` where `storageKey` is `"/gs/" + <id property of response from uploading to Cloud Storage>`

Not sure if this is supposed to serve images with the serving url on dev?  How to best diagnose?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Why are you storing a GS id into the BlobStore? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @rdodev the image.ServingURL needs a BlobKey, which one can get from a file in the GCS with `blobstore.BlobKeyForFile`, however, they are not being served.

Comment: my question is more like: why use blobstore at all? just push and serve objects directly from GCS, no?

Comment: @rdodev because I want a permanent image url form the Image Service https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/reference#ServingURL which allows me to crop, resize, and cache images.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question about this subject. It contains the Python code for reading and writing files (blobs) using Google Cloud storage and creating serving urls.

This codes works for images and other files like js, css and pdf's. in **both the SDK and GAE production**.

The code is here: [How to serve cloudstorage files using app engine SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174903/how-to-serve-cloudstorage-files-using-app-engine-sdk)

Comment: Hmm.  the `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket` url does not seem to be serving files for me.

Comment: Do you use GO? In Python we have a Cloud Storage Client, which is part of the SDK.

Comment: yes, Im using go.  There is an SDK, which provides these methods.  However, they the URLs that are created don't seem to be working..  not sure if this is a local dev server limitation or something else entirely.

Comment: it seems that GO on GAE is a joke really. Even $PHP is more stable than GO. WTF